# Getting PC hardware info through pi zero

Tags: raspbian, usb, ssh, hardware, pi-zero

I am trying to get some info about the hardware on my PC through my pi zero for example CPU temperature and RAM speed etc. I have connected my pi zero through a single usb cable into my PC (I am able to perform a successful SSH connection between my PC and my Pi). Then when I have this information I'd like to show it on a 2x16 LCD screen or later maybe a touchscreen (This, I know how to do, I just don't know how to get the hardware info).

Thanks :p

Comment: Using a PC or getting information about a PC is not a Pi specific question.

Comment: I would say it includes a pretty big part about a pi

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question and highlight the Pi part.

Comment: There are a couple of commands that may exist on your PC -systeminfo and msinfo32 and possibly some of https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/system-information - create a file from their output and copy that over ssh to the Pi.  As above, this is not really a Pi question as you state you can get the display to work.